# Get xsuperobject to parse unnamed array to tobject structure

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am using Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update 2, and am trying to use [XSuperObject / XSuperJSON](https://github.com/onryldz/x-superobject) to take a JSON response from a 3rd party provider and parse it into an object structure.

Here is the JSON:

```json
[ 
  {
    "yardNumber": 10,
    "links": [
      {
        "rel": "yardSaleList",
        "href": "<url address>"
      }
    ],
    "yardName": "Yard A",
    "auctionDate": "1/25/17"
  },
  {
    "yardNumber": 10,
    "links": [
      {
        "rel": "yardSaleList",
        "href": "<url>"
      }
    ],
    "yardName": "Yard B",
    "auctionDate": "1/25/17"
  }
]
```

My code is something like this:

```pascal
TLinkItem = class
public
  [alias('rel')]
  rel: String;
  [alias('href')]
  href: string;
end;    

TPartItem = class
public
  [alias('yardNumber')]
  YardNumber: integer;
  [alias('links')]
  Links: TObjectList<TLinkItem>;
  [alias('yardName')]
  YardName: string;
  [alias('auctionDate')]
  AuctionDate: String; 
  destructor destroy; override;
end;

TPartItems = class  /// not used because this is an unnamed JSON array
public
  [alias('ItemData')] 
  ItemData : TObjectList<TPartItem>;     
end;

...

destructor TPartItems.destroy;
begin
  freeandnil(Links);
  inherited;
end;
```

If it were a named array, I could use the above object to refer to the name
of the array:

```pascal
myData := TPartItems.FromJSON(jsonString); 
showmssage(myData.ItemData.count.toString);
```

But because this is an unnamed array, I can't do that.

I'm hoping I have just missing some kind of detail here that I could not find. 
Until now, this has worked pretty well with other data suppliers, but 
I have never run across an unnamed JSON array like this.

Comment: Well strictly speaking, that is valid JSON code. The problem appears to be that XSuperObject missed this implementation, or it just wasn't figured out. After all, you can't reference anything nameless by its name. You may have to bite the bullet and use SO manually the old fashioned way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What *exactly* is stopping you from parsing an unnamed array into a `TPartItems` object?  Can you please be more specific? How is `TPartItems.FromJSON()` actually invoking XSuperObject/XSuperJSON? You did not show that code. People cannot tell you what's wrong if you don't show what you are really doing. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve).

Comment: That is what it looks like to me then. I couldn't find anything that talked about it anywhere nor after looking at it the source on how to treat it without going old fashion

@RemyLebeau 
I  gave example code? Doesn't parse because there is no such named pair called ItemData, it is unnamed in the JSON. That is my issue. How would I go about declaring the structure of something which has no name. Which it looks XSuperObject doesn't handle. 

Not sure what else I can give you. I gave the whole object structure and how it would work, so other than that, i just old fashioned it and it works.

Comment: @StevenChesser: I was not aware that `FromJSON()` is a `TObject` helper method implemented by XSuperObject itself. I thought it was a method in your own code. In that case, I looked at XSuperObject's source and do not see anything that would allow the JSON you have shown to stream an unnamed array into `TPartItems` directly. So, why not just wrap the JSON array inside of a JSON object that gives the array a name? `myData := TPartItems.FromJSON('{ItemData: ' + jsonString + '}');`

Comment: @Remy always coming up with clever ideas.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at XSuperObject's source and do not see anything that would allow the JSON you have shown to stream an *unnamed* array into `TPartItems` directly. So, I would suggest simply wrapping the JSON array inside of a JSON object that gives the array a name, eg:

```
myData := TPartItems.FromJSON('{ItemData: ' + jsonString + '}');
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly you can do addition to @Remy Lebeau

```
sResponse := '{"arr":'+sResponse+'}'; 
XSO := SO(sResponse);

for I := 0 to XSO.A['arr'].Length-1 do
begin
   XSO.A['arr'].o[i].S['yardNumber'];
   //....
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can´t comment, I´ll complement @AhmetSinav

answer:

```
res := idHttp.get('api/ajustes/127');
objReg := SO(res);
for i := 0 to objReg.A['registros'].Length-1 do
begin
   ShowMessage(objReg.A['registros'].o[i].S['id']);
   //....
end;
```