# Decode json using uJson for delphi

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-2007, ujson

I have a JSON file that looks like this and I'm trying to decode it, but with no luck:

```json
[
  {
    "FirstName": "Kim",
    "Surname": "Jensen"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Amery",
    "Surname": "Mcmillan"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Denton",
    "Surname": "Burnett"
  }
  ...
]
```

Using uJson with Delphi 2007, I know how to extract the data when the array has a name like this:

```json
{
  "Names": [
    {
      "FirstName": "Kim",
      "Surname": "Jensen"
    },
    {
      "FirstName": "Amery",
      "Surname": "Mcmillan"
    },
    {
      "FirstName": "Denton",
      "Surname": "Burnett"
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

```pascal
var
  json: TJSONObject;
  Text: String;
  i: Integer;
begin
  json := TJSONObject.create(jsontext);

  for i:=0 to json.getJSONArray('Names').Length -1 do
  begin
    Text := json.getJSONArray('Names').getJSONObject(i).optString('FirstName');
    ...
  end;
end;
```

But, this array has no name, and I have tried almost everything I can think of and still this simple thing has taking me hours to figure out.

Comment: See [Get xsuperobject to parse unnamed array to tobject structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41557618/576719)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delphi parse JSON array or array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534011/delphi-parse-json-array-or-array)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the JSON you are having trouble with, the top-level data *is* the array, so you need to parse it using `TJSONArray` instead of `TJSONObject`.

```pascal
var
  json: TJSONArray;
  Text: String;
  i: Integer;
begin
  json := TJSONArray.create(jsontext);
  try
    for i := 0 to json.Length-1 do
    begin
      Text := json.getJSONObject(i).optString('FirstName');
      ...
    end;
  finally
    json.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: For some reason I always thought that I had to add it to an Object first before I could access it. Thanks Remy.